# Run web.py python app with command line arguments that are not port number

Tags: python

I need to provide an xml file as a command line argument to my web.py app. However, the library automatically takes the first command line argument as the port number, which I do not provide as an argument. Is there some sort of trick or workaround to provide an xml file as a command line argument?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import web
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file = sys.argv[1]

urls = ('/get_user/(.*)', 'get_user',
    '/users', 'list_users')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

def read_xml(xml_file):
    with open(xml_file, 'r') as f:
        tree = ET.parse(f)
    return tree.getroot()

root = read_xml(file)

class list_users:
    def GET(self):
        output = 'Users:\n'
        for child in root:
            print 'child', child.tag, child.attrib
            output += (str(child.attrib['user']) +
            ': ' + str(child.attrib['name']) + ', ' + str(child.attrib['email'] + '\n'))
        return output

class get_user:
    def GET(self, name):
        for child in root:
            if child.attrib['name'] == name:
                output += str(child.attrib['name']) + ", " + str(child.attrib['email'])
            return output
        output = "The user (" + name + ") couldn't be found!"
        return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from moving your XML file attribute to `sys.argv[2]` and providing a port number to satisfy the web library? I believe it uses 8080 as the default, so you could just pass that to it anyway

Comment: Thanks, I think that solution will work for my current needs

Comment: Cool. Looking at the docs for web.py, I think that is definitely the easiest workaround